# How to change Menu Bar system preferences programmatically?

Tags: swift, macos

I've read that NSUserDefaults can change System Preferences of a Mac programmatically, such as the Dock with defaults write com.apple.dock, but I can't seem to find a way to change the Menu Bar's preferences.

The specific setting I'm trying to change: [image: screenshot of Dock & Menu Bar settings, with arrow pointing to the ‘Automatically hide and show the menu bar in full screen’ checkbox]

Comment: I suspect it's stored in  `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`. Take a snapshot of that file before and after the change (and wait a minute for the setting to be persisted), and diff the two. If there's a change, you should be able to see the key under which is was stored

Comment: Unfortunately no, it wasn't in that file.